# difficulty with mysql load data infile

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL and I'm just having a little difficulty with the syntax for load data infile.

So my data is in the format below and I've created a table with 2 columns one for ints and another for varchars.

```
0,Albert
1,America
2,American
3,April
4,Austrian
5,Badcock's
```

This is the code I was trying but it just puts everything into the first row of the varchar column, could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

```
load data infile 'C:/temp/correct.csv'
into table correct_spellings
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've copied+pasted your data, it is impossible to tell whether lines are truly terminated by `\r\n`.

I suggest that you first try without the `LINES TERMINATED BY...` clause. Let MySQL auto-detect this for you.

If this does not work, try again, this time with only `\n`, or only `\r`.

Sorry - I can't provide with a definite answer, you'll have to test...

Comment: Dropped the 'LINES TERMINATED BY' clause, that worked perfectly. Thanks so much for your help!